# Most active users on tag Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump, data-analysis

I was wondering, and I searched a bit but found nothing, is there a query on [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that will show the most active users on a certain tag on a overflow site?

Like someone who frequently answers questions or something similar to that.

What would that query look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just built [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/455710/who-are-the-top-users-on-a-tag?TagName=c%23) like that, based upon an older query Sam wrote.

You can provide the tag name, and it will count all upvotes on the posts under that tag.

Full SEDE query:

```
DECLARE @TagName varchar(40) = ##TagName:string##

SELECT --TOP 20 
    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) ranking,
    TagName,
    Users.Id [User Link],
    DisplayName,
    COUNT(*) AS UpVotes 
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
    INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
WHERE 
    Tags.TagName = @TagName
GROUP BY TagName, Users.Id,DisplayName 
ORDER BY UpVotes DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on [Patrick's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277309/295232), [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/455713) is one which counts the *number of answers*, which IMHO fits your request

> Like someone who frequently answers questions or something similar to that.

better.

```
DECLARE @TagName varchar(40) = ##TagName:string##

SELECT --TOP 20 
    TagName,
    DisplayName,
    COUNT(*) AS Posts 
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Users ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id
WHERE 
    Tags.TagName = @TagName AND
    Posts.PostTypeId = 2
GROUP BY TagName, DisplayName 
ORDER BY Posts DESC
```

Comment: See my updated query for ranking and user id links.